# Intercepting real non-static method calls with Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermockito, intercept

Is there any way, using `Mockito` or `PowerMockito`, to intercept calls to non-static methods of an object, or at least of a singleton object?

An example is provided by the following classes:

```
public class Singleton {

  private static Singleton INSTANCE = null;

  private Singleton(Object parameter) {}

  public static Singleton getInstance(Object parameter) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
      INSTANCE = new Singleton(parameter);
    }
    return INSTANCE;
  }

  public String process(String a, String b) {
    return (a + b);
  }

  // Other methods
}

public class Foreign {

  private Foreign() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Singleton.getInstance(new Object()).process("alpha", "beta"));
  }
}
```

The `Singleton` object is created in a `Foreign` class, outside the control of some test code (not shown above). Neither of these two classes can be modified. The objective is to intercept calls to the non-static `process()` method in the test code so that, for certain values, a different result is returned, e.g. the call

```
Singleton.getInstance(new Object()).process("alpha", "beta");
```

mocked to return `"alpha-beta"` instead of the expected `"alphabeta"`.

One solution could be intercepting the `Singleton.getInstance()` method to instantiate a custom subclass of the Singleton, e.g. using

```
public class SubSingleton extends Singleton {

  public SubSingleton(Object parameter) {
    super(parameter);
  }

  public String process(String a, String b) {
    if ("alpha".equals(a) && "beta".equals(b)) {
      return a + "-" + b;
    }
    return super.process(a + b);
  }
}
```

Then, calls to the `Singleton.process()` method would be intercepted as in:

```
Object parameter = new Object();
PowerMockito.doReturn(new SubSingleton(parameter)).when(Singleton.class, "getInstance", parameter);
```

However, the `Singleton` class above only provides a private constructor, so it cannot be extended. Using `PowerMockito.whenNew()` to return a partial mock (spy) will also not work, since the `Singleton` class does not provide a no-args constructor.

Can the desired mocking be implemented in any other way? Can it be done for non-singleton classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can use whenNew for objects with constructor with some params:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Singleton.class)
public class SingletonPrivateNewTest {

    @Mock
    Singleton singletonMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Singleton.class)
                .withAnyArguments()
                .thenReturn(singletonMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMockNew() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(singletonMock.process(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("sasa");
        Foreign.main(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

Secondly, why not stub getInstance instead of new:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Singleton.class)
public class SingletonPrivateNewTest {

    @Test
    public void testMockNew() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Singleton.class);
        Singleton singletonMock = Mockito.mock(Singleton.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Singleton.getInstance(any())).thenReturn(singletonMock);
        Mockito.when(singletonMock.process(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("sasa");
        Foreign.main(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

Thirdly, to intercept the process method:

- create real singleton
- create a mock singleton
- mock static getInstance to return the mock. NOTE: you must call mockStatic after getting real instance.
- use thenAnswer to check the arguments on `process` call

  - return desired answer if they match desired pattern
  - else call real method on real singleton

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Singleton.class)
public class SingletonPrivateNewTest {

    @Test
    public void testMockNew() {
        var singletonReal = Singleton.getInstance(new Object());
        var singletonMock = Mockito.mock(Singleton.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Singleton.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Singleton.getInstance(any())).thenReturn(singletonMock);
        Mockito.when(singletonMock.process(anyString(), anyString())).thenAnswer((args) -> {
            String a = args.getArgument(0);
            String b = args.getArgument(1);
            if ("alpha".equals(a) && "beta".equals(b)) {
                return "sasa";
            } else {
                return singletonReal.process(a, b);
            }
        });
        Foreign.main(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

And finally, use a spy instead of a mock

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Singleton.class)
public class SingletonPrivateNewTest {

    @Test
    public void testMockNew() {
        var singletonReal = Singleton.getInstance(new Object());
        var singletonMock = Mockito.spy(singletonReal);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Singleton.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Singleton.getInstance(any())).thenReturn(singletonMock);
        Mockito.when(singletonMock.process("alpha", "beta")).thenReturn("sasa");
        // NOTE: real method is called for other args
        Foreign.main(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first method does not offer a solution, because it intercepts the `process()` of the mock object, not the singleton, which is what is actually used by `Foreign` and other classes, calling other methods of the `Singleton` class. The same applies to the second method, since the `Singleton` class has other methods too (clarified in the question). The third approach should work for singletons, as the spying happens on a real object. Any applicability to non-singletons? +1 and thanks for the answer awyway.

Comment: 1. My answer gives you stages of the solution. The first shows that you can use whenNew when there are params to the constructor, which you suggested to be impossible. 2. If there are other methods and you want to intercept only some calls, 3rd and 4th snippet is the way to go (my preference goes to 4th). 3. I am quite puzzled with `Singleton.getInstance(Object parameter)` that takes a param and ignores it if the singleton already exists. 4. Applicability to non-singletons - I would need a concrete example.

Comment: 1. Thanks for your answer, +1 and accepted. The meaning of my comment is that `whenNew()` does not offer a solution, because it supplies a mocked object, not the real singleton. 2. Agreed on the 4th, as per my previous comment. 3. The code is a simplified example, the parameter can be anything and there can be more than one. 4. Any application, as long as more than one instances exists, used by foreign classes. A private constructor with parameters is not always usable if mocked arguments are passed, because calls to the real methods may not produce valid results.